# how can i invoke a function after page is done loading? (and only then..)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having trouble with some jquery code.
in my HTML page I use ajax to get some info, and then I'm changing an HTML element
with `$("#id").html(...)`.

The problem is, I also have a `$(document).ready` code which I wanna call only once
when the page is done loading, but after each change in the html with the `$("#id").html(...)`
the code is called once again.

How can I run the `$(document).ready` code only once?

Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // this code will run not only once...
}

function f(){
    $("#id").html(...);
}
```

Comment: Define "done loading". All content? The DOM? What? Is your second requirement the same? Linked? Distinct?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var run = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(!run) {
        ...
        run = true;
    }
});
```

...or...

```
$(window).load(function() {
    ...
});
```

The first one will make sure it is only run once; the 2nd one is run when the entire page is finished loading (useful if you need to resize things once images have finished loading).

Answer (score 1):

From the comments on [the `.ready` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> Looks like .ready() fires not only when page initially has settled the
>   DOM, but apparently also after changes to the DOM. This is an issue if
>   your ready handler changes the DOM. That will result in ready() firing
>   more than once. It may result in an endless loop if each invocation
>   adds yet more to the DOM. Firefox and IE behave differently to this,
>   including different error messages, and leaving the page display in
>   different states. So, if ready() modifies the DOM, then it would be
>   wise to have a way to check whether ready has already been fired.
>
> Replying to self: Well it appears that part of the problem is not that
>   the ready function fires again (though that is possible aparently),
>   but that changing the DOM causes the script that *creates* the ready
>   function to fire again, adding an additional ready function, etc etc.
>   This seems to happen if the javascript is embedded in the html at a
>   point beyond (or contained in) the part of the DOM that the ready
>   handler modifies. (Obviously would be better to put script that
>   creates a ready function in the document head, but in this case that's
>   not an option.) Problem fixed by checking a global flag variable to be
>   undefined before executing jQuery(document).ready(...).

If this might be your problem, you can adopt the same solution:

```
var onLoadFired = false;
$(document).ready(function() {

   /* Ensure this function only runs once */
   if (onLoadFired) {
      return;
   }
   else {
      onLoadFired = true;
   }

   /* Business logic */

   // .. your code here ..
});
```

Or, better, move your handler into a separate script file that's included by a `script` tag in your page's `head` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   ...
});
```